# Firebase's Facebook login on React-native-android

Tags: firebase, react-native, facebook-authentication

I've been trying to get the Facebook login snippet from Firebase's documentation to work but I get the following console error:

> window.open is not a function

What is the correct way to implement Firebase's Facebook login on a React Native app ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Firebase Twitter Authentication with React Native?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795853/how-to-use-firebase-twitter-authentication-with-react-native)

Answer (score 3):

This was answered in [How to use Firebase Twitter Authentication with React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795853/how-to-use-firebase-twitter-authentication-with-react-native)

It's because the JavaScript version of Firebase was written for the web and not React Native. Most of the API works correctly except for:

- **Social authentication**. Uses browser functions to open a new window or
  redirect.
- **Caching data and authentication**. Looks like it's built
  for synchronous local storage instead of React Native's asynchronous
  storage.

I started using Firebase Web for my React Native app and implemented Facebook login using the Facebook iOS SDK as a native module then passing the token to `authWithOAuthToken`.

Now that I've found persistence doesn't work either I'm considering using the Firebase iOS and Android APIs wrapping only the required methods as native modules instead of trying to re-implement persistence.