# Is there a React Native "WEB code safe guard"?

Tags: javascript, web, react-native

I read this [question about firebases 3 party login integration not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940326/firebases-facebook-login-on-react-native-android), and the reason was, because it used functions not available in the react native platform, such as localStorage.* or window.open.

What seemed strange to me, that the user got a "window.open is not a function" error, instead of something akin to "this function is not supported on react native".

Is there a script/open source library that can warn me, like the paragraph above, that I'm trying to use features not available within node?

Comment: If you are interested in something beyond eslint verifying your own code, it may be helpful to clarify your question by editing "that I'm trying to use features..." to instead read "that I'm trying, or a library I am using tries, to use features..."

Answer (score 1):

These features are not stripped away per se, it's simply not a part of the JS runtime environment outside of a browser context.  But you're in luck!  There is a great way to warn about these sorts of things [using eslint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring).

In your .eslintrc file, configure the environment to be node, and not the browser:

```
// .eslintrc
{
    env: {
        node: true,
        browser: false
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this will verify **your** code, but it won't verify that third party tools aren't expecting browser APIs behind the scenes.

Comment: Great idea Adam, thanks! Though my question refers specifically to the use case of incorporating third party scripts.

Comment: @AgafadaEm Then no, I do not believe it's possible. :(